# paypal cancel transaction through merchant API

Tags: java, paypal

Is there a way to cancel or reverse a pending transaction (pending due to echeck clearance) which was done by DoExpressCheckout through the Merchant API.

I found No specific API given for this purpose other than a full refund which is under a refund fee.

Comment: Have you tried [DoVoid][1]


  [1]: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoVoid_API_Operation_NVP/

Answer (score 0):

Echecks, like any other check is an ACH transaction and cannot be cancelled or voided. it will pend until it clears; you can refund the payment at that point. There is a setting within the PayPal account that allows the merchant to block echecks and this is what I would recommend. Most buyers are unaware they are paying you by echeck; it usually occurs when the buyer does not have a backup funding source to allow instant payment. The only restriction is that you cant block echeck payments for eBay items. You can block echeck transactions by navigating in your PayPal account to Profile > My Selling Tools > Block payments. Click checkbox for Block the following payments:
Pay with eCheck or German bank transfer for all website payments except eBay.